# Is it possible to transform an interface/type alias to a literal string type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to transform an interface/type alias or even Primitive type(e.g. string, number, boolean...) to a literal string type?

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

type Literal = `${string & Person}`
```

What I want to get is :

```
type Literal = 'Person'
```

but this is the result :

```
type Literal = `${string & Person}`
```

Here's another example :

```
type Name = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

type Pet = {
    dog: number,
    cat: number,
    possum: number
}

type Person = {
    name: Name
    pet: Pet
    age: number
}
```

If we want to get the literal types of keys, we can simply do :

```
type Keys = keyof Person; // 'name' | 'pet' | 'age'
```

And we can also get the values by doing :

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type values = Values<Person>; // number | Name | Pet
```

But instead of getting `number | Name | Pet`,
Is there a way to get `'number' | 'Name' | 'Pet'`?

I know I can get `'number' | 'Name' | 'Pet'` by manipulating the key name, but what if the key name and the property name are so different like `age: number`,

Is there any way to transform an interface/type alias or even primitive type(e.g. string, number, boolean...) to a literal string type?

Comment: You’d have to write your own utility type to do this and it would only work for specific names you hardcode; TS has no “serialize a type name as a string literal type” functionality.  What is the use case, though?  A  custom compiler error message or something?

Comment: @jcalz Soory for late replay, there isn't a specific use case, jut purely out of curiosity, thank you.